# Jolt: concat of continues key values at the end

Tags: json, jolt

I have one requirement in jolt to concat based on the key values.. key value may get increased. like PPfullname,PPfullname1... PPfullname2...

**input** :

```json
[
  {
    "policy": "Name",
    "PAFrstNm": "John"
  },
  {
    "PALastNm": "Jammy",
    "policy": "Name"
  },
  {
    "policy": "Name",
    "PPFrstNm": "sam"
  },
  {
    "policy": "Name",
    "PPLastNm": "jim"
  },
  {
    "policy": "Name",
    "PPFrstNm1": "jun"
  },
  {
    "PPLastNm1": "san",
    "policy": "Name"
  }
]
```

**expected output**:

```json
[
  {
    "PAfullname": "John Jammy",
    "policy": "Name"
  },
  {
    "PPfullname": "sam jim",
    "policy": "Name"
  },
  {
    "PPfullname1": "jun san",
    "policy": "Name"
  }
]
```

Comment: PAfullname I got the logic.. where as PPfullname, PPfullname1, and 2 how can we group .. or anything we can try in shift to concat... @barbaros ozhan.

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan, if we have third values and how the join will work. First +mid+ last.( In the following order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following spec

```json
[
  { // group by LastN/FrstN removed key names 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*LastN*": {
          "@": "@2,policy.&(1,1)fullna&(1,2)"
        },
        "*FrstN*": {
          "@": "@2,policy.&(1,1)fullna&(1,2)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // concatenate the components of the arrays respectively 
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*ful*": "=join(' ',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "[#2].&",
          "$1": "[#2].policy" // deliver back the policy attribute to those objects
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: if we have third values and how the join will work. First +mid+ last.( In the following order). can you pleas provide an input with above